# Backreference in javascript regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, backreference

I can find a lot of information about getting the capture groups of a regex in the javascript `replace` function, using `$1`, `$2`, etc.. But what I really need is a way to backreference a capture group in the regex itself.

I need to match the following three strings with one regex:

```
<--text-->
<**text**>
<++text++>
```

where `text` is actually `[a-zA-Z]+`.

I have this pattern already in Ruby:

```
/<([-+*]{2})(.+)\1>/
```

Never mind that I used `(.+)` here, but I'm interested to  know how I can achieve the `\1` backreference in javascript. Any ideas?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-backreference

Comment: Like @JamesAllardice said, have tried it?  That regex works fine for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could you not just try it? It works the same way:

```
var regex = /<([-+*]{2})(.+)\1>/;

var str = "<--text-->";
regex.exec(str); // ["<!--text-->", "--", "text"]

str = "<--text**>";
regex.exec(str); // null
```